# Corda Node getting JVM OutOfMemory Exception when trying to load data

Tags: corda

**Background:**
We are trying to load data in our Custom CorDapp(Corda-3.1) using jmeter.
Our CorDapp is distributed across Six nodes(Three Parties, Two Notaries and One Oracle).
The Flow being executed in order to load data is having very minimal business logic, has three participants and requires two parties to sign the transaction.
Below is the environment, configuration and test details:
Server: Ubuntu 16.04
Ram: 8GB
Memory allocation to Corda.jar: 4GB
Memory allocation to Corda-webserver.jar : 1GB
JMeter Configuration- Threads(Users): 20 (1 transaction per second per thread)

**Result:**
Node B crashed after approx 21000 successful transactions(in approximately 3 hours and 30 mins) with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". After some time other nodes crashed due to continuous "handshake error" with Node B.
We analyzed heap dump using Eclipse MAT and found out that more than 21000 instances of hibernate SessionFactoryImpl were created which occupied more than 85% of the memory on Node B.

We need to understand why Corda network is creating so many objects and persisting them in memory.
We are continuing our investigation as we are not 100% sure if this is entirely Corda bug.
Solution to the problem is critical in our pursuit to continue further tests.
Note - We have more details about our investigation but we are unable to attach them here but can send over email.

Comment: upload on git and share the link if possible.

Comment: Can you share the JMeter script?

Comment: @opticyclic the issue has been resolved.!
do you need JMeter script for your own reference?

Comment: Yes please. Would you be able to share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing in Java, it is likely that the issue you're encountering has already been fixed by https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1411

The fix is not available in Corda 3.1 yet, but the JIRA ticket provides a workaround. You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` on any subclasses of `MappedSchema` that you've defined. This should fix the issue you're observing.

Comment: overriding the equals and hashcode method of the super class solved the issue, I successfully posted 100,000 transactions, with corDapp still ready to accept more transactions :)